# Is there any way to get Blobstore to generate or provide a thumbnail for a video?

Tags: google-app-engine, thumbnails, blobstore

Whether it is while the video is being uploaded to the Blobstore or any time afterwards, including way after I get the servingUrl from the Blobkey: is there a way to ask the Blobstore to create a thumbnail for a video? Or must I upload one myself?

Comment: The Images API could provide thumbnails for images but i have never seen an out-of-the box method to get a thumbnail for videos. Of course you could read the video file and generate one yourself. I have no idea how complex such a functionality would be though.

Comment: Konqi has the right of it, there won't be an out of the box way to get that. You'll need to either upload the thumbnail yourself, or to read the video, choose a frame, save that as an image, put that in a thumbnail (wow.... that sounds awfully complicated)

Comment: It will be better if we can add answer below instead commenting to question without code.